# accent on capital Greek letters

Tags: greek

I am writing in Greek and the title of chapters and sections on each page appear with accent on capital letters. I am trying `\chapter[{text}]` to fix it but it doesn't work. What can I do? Please help!!

Comment: Welcome, we need to see a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) to reproduce your issue.